# Using UML Class diagrams in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, uml

I am using IntelliJ Ultimate, version 2017.2 for Mac.  I love the way you can use the included plugin to make UML diagrams and the circular engineering from the UML to Java and vis-versa.  I have seen plugins that other people use with the IntelliJ Community Edition, but I have the Ultimate Edition.

The JetBrains website manual for the UML ( https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/class-diagram-toolbar-context-menu-and-legend.html ) shows two toolbar icons for "extends or implements" and "dependancies".  But in my UML diagram toolbar, I have icons for "show dependancies" and "edge creation mode".

I can not find any documentation or tutorials that explain how to use the GUI with these "newer" toolbar buttons.  Am I missing something simple?  I can create the associations in code and it updates the UML correctly.  But specifically, I can't find how to use the GUI to create an association or to change the multiplicity.

In addition, I move the classes around, and it keeps resetting them to default instead of leaving them where I put them.

Is there anyone familiar with this?

Comment: Did you try the Edge Creation Mode? It's specifically designed for adding relations between classes (implement/extend).

Comment: Yes, and here's what I've found with that:  you have to first select a different class and then click on the class you want to make the connection line from, then drag it to the class you wish it to point to.  And you can only do that when you have the "Edge Creation Mode" selected.  That creates an extend relationship.  Then you can right click on one of the classes and choose refactor, "Replace Inheritance with Delegation..." to get an association.  The GUI seems to act finicky still, and the one thing I can't find is how to change the multiplicity in the GUI.